# Which option is better to use as param in a function: entire object or properties as vars

Tags: function, architecture, parameters

I'm asking myself which can be the better way to handle parameters. Given an objet like this:

```
objet
  property1
  property2
```

lets say a function needs to receive it, at least property1 and property2 , so what is better, this?

```
function(param/property1, param/property2)
```

or this?

```
function(entire_object)
```

I can guess that for example passing the entire object isn't good for the performance while using params says exactly what function needs... and at the other side, we can say passing an object can be more dynamic. I don't know, let's discuss!

Answer (score 0):

> I can guess that for example passing the entire object isn't good for the performance

This is probably wrong. You can pass the object as a reference/pointer.

Passing an object as a reference/pointer can be considered as "passing an interface".

Comparing between "passing an interface" and "passing individual parameters", the former is likely to be a more stable interface. Lets say, your function implementation needs to change and you need an additional value. You can always pick up more information from the interface without any change to the function signature. This would not be true if you were passing individual parameters.

A disadvantage of passing an interface - From caller perspective, if the individual parameters are more readily available, it can be cumbersome to create an object just to pass to a function.